# Choice of current sensing reisistor

Tags: resistors, current-measurement

I need measure a 10A AC current, and need a 50mOhm current sensing resistor with tolerance <= 1% and good temperature stability. I find there are some choices, such as Vishay's [RH,NH series](http://www.vishay.com/docs/30201/30201.pdf), or [this type](http://www.topresistor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/FL.pdf) made by special copper alloy as below:

[image]

Which one is better? Any other suggestions?

Comment: 50mOhm will dissipate almost 5A at full current. Do you need that value because of the amplifier you are using?

Comment: @gbulmter - 50 mOhm is 0.05 Ohms so it will dissipate 5 watts with 10 amperes through it.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? You need to give some clues, either the use-case, or the constraints. Also I can't open the link http://www.topresistor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/FL.pdf  Please give enough information to track the part down (manufacturer and part number).

Comment: Whoops yeah, on mobile, meant power. IMO I'd revisit the analog solution as a 50mOhm resistor is 100*0.05 or 5W dissipated which is a lot. Maybe improving gain or changing parts could help, but need to know more.

Comment: @Barry - Glerk! You are right, \$10^2 \times 0.05=5\$, I failed to press \$x^2\$ Sorry. It should be Watts though :-)

Comment: You want a shunt resistor. I couldn't open "this type" link, but "RH,NH series" is certainly not a shunt

Comment: http://ecee.colorado.edu/~ecen4517/components/parts/OAR.pdf

Comment: Why not use a smaller shunt, with a op-amp? This way the shunt will not heat up, and any precision resistor can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "RN, RH" are wirewound with no hint about inductance, so depending on your use case, they might be unusable.

I can't open the link for http://www.topresistor.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/FL.pdf so it may be no use either.

I would have expected something like [50mΩ ±1.0% 7W](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/surface-mount-fixed-resistors/8702537/) SMD or [50mΩ 1% 5W](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/through-hole-fixed-resistors/7962450/) through hole, designed to be low-inductance current shunts, which specify inductance.

Maybe a lower resistance to reduce power loss.

Answer (score 1):

Why not look at a current transformer if you have the space and want to save power.Otherwise you could look at a hall effect device .The hall effect devices are now much cheaper and a bit smaller . If you must use a shunt then materials like Manganon or Constantine have good temp stability.

Comment: *Manganin* (Cu86Mn12Ni2) and *Constantan* (Cu55Ni45).

Comment: @ Spehro Pethany  I will try to spell .I had spelled the alloys the way others pronounced them .My screen name is not without an element of truth .